# In defining a Python function, can I easily define a parameter as optional, with a default to another parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

For example:

```
class student():
    def __init__(self, name, pref_name=None):
        self.name = name
        self.pref_name = pref_name if pref_name else name

bob = student('robert')
print("Bob name:", bob.name)
print('Bob preferred name:', bob.pref_name)
```

Can this be made any shorter and easier to read?

```
def __init__(self, name, pref_name=name)
```

unfortunately does not work.

Comment: No, your first sample is a canonical way for doing it.

Comment: One problem with the longer version is that it doesn't allow me to create students whose preferred name is actually None (obviously not the case with any real students that I know of, but I do want to do this with the actual Python class I'm working on)

Comment: nit: You don't need `()` in your class declaration.

Comment: @Iroh You can work around that by using a sentinel different from `None`. For example: `sentinel = object(); def __init__(self, name=sentinel): if name is sentinel: ...`. This is one of the very few cases in which using `is` is idiomatic python.